# Mutilple definition when linking object files

Tags: c++

Suppose we have `B.h`, `main.cpp` and `B.cpp`, `main.cpp` -> `main.obj` and `B.cpp` -> `B.obj`

Because of `separate compilation`, I think `main.obj` and `B.obj` should both have the definition of `class B`. Why it doesn't have the error:multiple definition of `B` when linking them?

**B.h**

```cpp
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class B {
    public:
        void fun();
    private:
        int x = 0;
};

#endif
```

**B.cpp**

```cpp
#include "B.h"

void B::fun() {
    
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "B.h"

int main() {
}
```

Comment: Because multiple **identical** definitions of a class are allowed.

Comment: See? People like your question. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither main.obj nor B.obj contains the definition of B. Object files have no need to contain type definitions, since the purpose of type definitions is to help *produce* the executable code and data for an object file. If two source files both operate on the same type, they both need to have that type’s definition included.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me where can I acquire these knowlege? Recommend some books?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list